# jQuery .click() doesn't fire when element is being modified with .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I've noticed that, on some platforms, it can be very difficult to click text that is being continually modified. The click event doesn't always trigger when the user clicks elements that are being modified resulting in an unresponsive interface.

For example, see this http://jsfiddle.net/hq9Rh/2/

In that example, there are four elements:

1. Replaces its text value every 100th millisecond and is almost impossible to click.
2. Replaces its text with an identical text. Is equally difficult to click.
3. Only writes to the element if the text is different. It's much more responsive to clicks.
4. Static, and perfectly clickable.

Here's the code to update the four elements:

```
setInterval(updateList, 100);
var iteration = 0;

function updateList(){
    iteration++;
    $(".updating").text(iteration);
    $(".replaceSameText").text("SameText");
    var oldText = $(".replaceDifferentText").text();
    var newText = "SameText";
    if(oldText != newText)
        $(".replaceDifferentText").text(newText);
}
```

What is going on? Is there any way to fix this?

I'm running Chrome 32 on Windows.

Comment: Y not use a clickable overlay and a variable for your timer that can be cleared?

Comment: @SpYk3HH: That (expanded a bit) could be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the text node within the element you're updating keeps getting destroyed and recreated, so the click may miss the text node.

You can avoid it by updating the value of the text node, rather than destroying and recreating it:

```
$(".replaceSameText")[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "SameText";
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hq9Rh/4/)

Comment: It works! Thanks! I will rethink my usage of .text in the future.

Comment: One problem with this solution is that it crashes if the element is empty (because firstChild is null). 

I tested .innerText (which I thought .text was) instead, and it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hq9Rh/5/

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't answer before because I was on a phone. :-P

Comment: @Palmish: Interesting about `innerText` (check compatibility, though). Yes, you'd want to handle the case where the element is completely empty (easily checked) and also where it has multiple children.